# Kafka Consumer not consuming from last commited offset after restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python, strimzi, confluent-kafka-python

I have a consumer polling from subscribed topic. It consumes each message and does some processing (within seconds), pushes to different topic and commits offset.

There are totally 5000 messages,

before restart - consumed 2900 messages and committed offset

after restart - started consuming from offset 0.

Even though consumer is created with same consumer group, it started processing messages from offset 0.

kafka version (strimzi) > 2.0.0
kafka-python == 2.0.1

Comment: can you show that the offsets were actually committed by showing the output of the command line tool `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` for your ConsumerGroup? How are you committing offsets? Why did you only consumed 2900 messages?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know how many **partitions** you have in your topic but when consumers are created within a same consumer group, they will consume records from different partitions ( We can't have two consumers in a consumer group that consume from the same partition and If you add a consumer the **group coordinator** will execute the process of **Re-balancing** to reassign each consumer to a specific partition).

I think the offset 0 comes from the property `auto.offset.reset` which can be :

- `latest`: Start at the latest offset in log
- `earliest`: **Start with the earliest record.**
- `none`: Throw an exception when there is no existing offset data.

But this property kicks in only if your consumer group doesn't have a valid offset committed.

**N.B:** Records in a topic have a **retention period** `log.retention.ms` property so your latest messages could be deleted when your are processing the first records in the log.

**Questions:** While you want to consume message from one topic and process data and write them to another topic why you didn't use Kafka Streaming ?